# Java parse int/long from binary literal string

Tags: java, literals

Java wonderfully provides `Long.decode` to parse most int formats, but not binary:

```
Long.decode("11") => 11
Long.decode("011") => 9
Long.decode("0x11") => 17
Long.decode("0b11") => java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

Is there a method that will parse a string containing a binary literal for me?

P.S.
I understand if I wanted to extract the radix/value myself I could use the binary form of `Long.parseLong`, but ideally what I'm looking for would be a function that could parse `"0b11"` without any pre-processing.

Comment: Technically that's a String not a binary literal. With a binary literal you would just write: `Long n = 0b11L;`

Comment: Good point, will update title.

Comment: This has been my pet-peeve. It also does not have a method to parse integer strings with [underscores](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-Underscores) (e.g. "100_000"), although it definitely accepts _literals_ with underscores.

Comment: Does that mean that to your knowledge no good solution exists?

Comment: Honestly, "No" is fine provided someone has evidence that it doesn't exist in core Java or the standard library. Alternatively a good community library would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way in the standard Java API. However, I would take a look at `Long.decode()` code and adapt it:

```
public static Long decode(String nm) throws NumberFormatException {
    int radix = 10;
    int index = 0;
    boolean negative = false;
    Long result;

    if (nm.length() == 0)
        throw new NumberFormatException("Zero length string");
    char firstChar = nm.charAt(0);
    // Handle sign, if present
    if (firstChar == '-') {
        negative = true;
        index++;
    } else if (firstChar == '+')
        index++;

    // Handle radix specifier, if present
    if (nm.startsWith("0x", index) || nm.startsWith("0X", index)) {
        index += 2;
        radix = 16;
    }
/// >>>> Add from here
    else if (nm.startsWith("0b", index) || nm.startsWith("0B", index)) {
        index += 2;
        radix = 2;
    }
/// <<<< to here
    else if (nm.startsWith("#", index)) {
        index ++;
        radix = 16;
    }
    else if (nm.startsWith("0", index) && nm.length() > 1 + index) {
        index ++;
        radix = 8;
    }

    if (nm.startsWith("-", index) || nm.startsWith("+", index))
        throw new NumberFormatException("Sign character in wrong position");

    try {
        result = Long.valueOf(nm.substring(index), radix);
        result = negative ? Long.valueOf(-result.longValue()) : result;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // If number is Long.MIN_VALUE, we'll end up here. The next line
        // handles this case, and causes any genuine format error to be
        // rethrown.
        String constant = negative ? ("-" + nm.substring(index))
                                   : nm.substring(index);
        result = Long.valueOf(constant, radix);
    }
    return result;
}
```

That's as close as it can be to the original method (Ctrl+clicking core Java methods is a good experience).

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't seem to provide one; however, is this code really that cumbersome that you need a library:

```
public static Long parseBinaryLiteral (String s)
{
    if (s == null)
        throw new NumberFormatException("null");

    // no need to check 0B
    s = s.toLowerCase();

    String p = "";

    if (s.startsWith("0b"))
        p = s.substring(2);
    else if (s.startsWith("-0b"))
        p = "-" + s.substring(3);
    else if (s.startsWith("+0b"))
        p = s.substring(3);
    else
        throw new NumberFormatException("For input string: \"" + s + "\"");

    return Long.parseLong(p, 2);
}
```

Comment: Cumbersome, no. But it's hard to write a correct implementation for this kind of stuff. For example your implementation has at least two bugs that I can spot without having read the spec. And I'd rather not read the spec.

Comment: What are the 2 bugs you see? I'm curious.

Comment: That's not a bug - it's just not supported yet :)

Comment: Haha, sure. But it's not trivial to make sure one's implementation is correct. I'm in the process of doing what you suggest now, but it's unfortunate that I'm putting in this effort and will likely still have "missing features" without realizing.

Comment: Good point. It's unfortunate that java doesn't support this - I'm a bit surprised. Hard to speculate as to why they didn't include it.

Comment: @user12341234 I updated my answer to include the support for leading +/-

Comment: Oh, and I forgot suffixes as well... The point here is not to make an exhaustive list of features, but to indicate that there are a lot of considerations in solving this problem correctly.

Comment: Your right, but even if you find a library, it may not even support the whole spec.

Comment: @user12341234 The Long.decode() method does not support suffixes, nor does it support underscores. That method doesn't even support the entire spec.